# Connections with many databases

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

We have a webapp where each client has their own db (approx. 700 at the moment).

In SubSonic 2, you had to wrap each call with the `SharedDBConnectionScope` passing in the right connection string to use, otherwise you ran the risk of one thread or client getting data from another thread or client.

In SubSonic3 is this still needed? Do I need to wrap the calls like I did in 2.x?

There are easy ways of switching the database now, but do I still have thread issues or can I do away with the call to `SharedDBConnectionScope`?

Answer (score 0):

SubSonic 3 greatly improved the way to create a provider from scratch or just passing a name and a connectionsctring:

Some Examples:

```
// Linq Templates:
var db = new YourDB("connectionstring goes here", "System.Data.SqlClient");

// SimpleRepository without app.config
IDataProvider provider = SubSonic.DataProviders.ProviderFactory.GetProvider(
    connectionString: "Server=localhost;Database=clientdb;Uid=root;",
    providerName: "MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
);
IRepository repository = new SimpleRepository(provider,
    SimpleRepositoryOptions.RunMigrations);
```

So basically you can create a provider or repository each time a client connects and use this in your class.

Comment: I understand that. I'm setting the connection string when I creat the IQuerySurface (YourDB in your example) and that works fine. But in 2.x you would get threading issues, client a would see clinet b's data unless you used SharedDBConnectionScope. I'm just wondering if those same threading issues exist or do the changes to how providers are created helpresolve that.